# Python: Beautiful Soup: Can't grab a full title from parsing

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to practice scraping by going to a video website, and scraping all the titles of the videos on the homepage. My only issue is, if the title is too long, it gets cut short using the .string function in BeautifulSoup.

Here is example HTML for parsing:

```html
<head>...</head>
<body class="home">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="vid_28" class="thumb-block ">
                <div class="thumb-inside">...</div>
                <p>
                    <a href="/vid_28/0/this_is_a_great_video_"
                    title="this is a great video">this is a great vi...</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the code I am attempting to print the title with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

links = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"thumb-block"})

for link in links:
    for tag in link.find_all("a")
        print(tag.string)
```

This code is working how I want it, except it's printing the string "this is a great vi..." which is cut short.

If you notice in the HTML, the text after "title=" never gets cut short.

How can I modify my code to acquire the text in parentheses after the "title=" within the  element, instead of acquiring the text that is cut off?

Comment: Then why don't you access the title attribute instead of `.string`?

Comment: It is because you are trying to access the string, which in your case is "this is a great vi..." and it is printing that. Try accessing the title attribute instead.

Comment: I've attempted replacing "tag.string" with "tag.title", all it does is return "None" in my console. I've read the documentation, but I can't see anything pointing to how to call other attributes besides the actual tag of title.

Comment: Can you post the actual URL that your trying to parse. Here, in your example the the string of the `a` tag has been set to "this is a great vi..." by you and the output you're getting isn't cut off. It is in fact giving you the correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my problem, I found it in documentation after re-reading it multiple times.

If you want to print any attribute which I wanted the "title=", I had to change the `print(tag.string)` to `print(tag['title'])`

This is what @Rawring and @ChaoticTwist suggested first, but I wasn't sure what they meant by access the title attribute until now.

Thank you all for your time.